# Is there a way to set global permissions for all files created by a perl script?

Tags: perl, file-permissions

I have a script that runs CPAN::Mini::Inject actions and has an App::Cache. It works fine, but sometimes i need to run it from different user accounts, which is when i run afoul of file permissions, since some files are automatically created with 0740 permissions.

Right now i'm using a crutch of `system("chmod -R a+w .")`, but i'm not liking that.

Is there a way i can enforce, for the scope of the script, a global file mode of 0777 for all created files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `umask` built-in to change the default file mode. For instance `umask 0` will change the default mode to 0777.

BUT, if files are being created with rights 0740, it probably means that CPAN::Mini::Inject is setting the permissions explicitly and the umask may not do any effect.

In that later case, you will have to dive into the module souce code, look for the place where permissions are set and see if you can overload it in anyway. Another option is to just submit a feature request to the author.

BTW, the CPAN::Mini module accepts a `dirmode` option to set directory permissions.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're assuming permissions are being set explicitly... It's entirely reasonable that some users/systems may have a default umask of 0037, or at least 0057. (Setting execute for user but not group seems a bit odd, though, which argues to me more for a local umask setting chosen by someone who doesn't fully understand unix permissions rather than it being explicitly set by CPAN::Mini::Inject. Also, I did a quick check over the source of CPAN::Mini::Inject and didn't see anything that sets permissions unless the `dirmode` option is set.)

Comment: 0037 and 0057 are reasonable but in my experience very rare, that's why I say *probably*!

Comment: Thanks, i wasn't aware that umask could be used in a reverse mode. :)

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [umask](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/umask.html).